# Shop/Location management extension

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

does somebody know about an extension with that i can manage and display different shops with the following deatils:

- adress
- zip code
- opening time
- skills at this location
- a map
- phone number

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in different ways:

- With one [Classified Ads](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/ads-a-affiliates/classified-ads) extension.
- Implement a [Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/directory-a-documentation/directory) extension.
- Also you can create your own custom solution using a [Content Construction Kit](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/authoring-a-content/content-construction).

Most of the options mentioned above have the functionality to add the fields that you
 mention in your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is probably too broad to provide an accurate answer but I'll throw in a suggestion anyway.

FocalPoint is free and does a great job of displaying location information including custom content like a CCK so you can add fields for the address, zip code, opening times, skills, map, phone number and whatever else you like.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/focalpoint